# TextInputType.number only accepts numbers from an english keyboard

Tags: flutter, dart, keyboard

i am making a multilingual shopping app and i have arabic and anthor language ++ english as the languages the user can pick, when someone wants to order they have to fill a form where it asks for their phone number and they can type it in a textfield, however if their keyboard is already on arabic or another language and they press numbers nothing shows in the text field, anybody knows how i can fix that?

i've tested it both on simu and real iphone 11 device.

Comment: Didi you try with an arabic typeface?

Comment: you can file that as a bug in flutter github

Answer (score 0):

Insert this code snippet into the TextFormField

```
inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
              FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp('[0-9۰-۹]')),
            ],
```